# Working with IO Monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If i have two constants:

```
type A = Int  
type B = Int
```

and then apply the function:

```
Number :: String −> (Int −> Bool) −> IO Int
Number n = do
    num <- fmap getNumber getLine
    if num >0 || num <= A || num <= B then num else putStrln "Invalid Number!"
```

is this correct ?

Comment: This is actually quite far from even being syntactically correct. It's impossible to understand as is: could you please write a minimal example and try to compile it, presenting all compiler errors? I don't think the IO monad is causing issues here.

Comment: 1. `type A = Int` doesn't represent a constant. It is just a renaming of the type `Int`. If you want to write a constant, just define a top level function like so `_A = 3.14`. 2. Where is `getNumber` defined? What does it do? 3. `Number` is not a valid function name. 4. `num` has type `Num a => a` and `putStrLn ".."` has type `IO ()`. They can't be in the then/else branches of the same if statement.

Comment: If it were correct then you'd be able to compile it.  As your question stands, the obvious and correct answer is simply "no".  Perhaps you should ask a series of more specific questions that speak to any confusions you have.  From what I can tell, those questions could include "what is a type alias?" and "What is the syntactic form of function definitions?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line `num <- fmap getNumber getLine` is correct (if `getNumber = read`), but second line is not

```
if num >0 || num <= A || num <= B then num else putStrln "Invalid Number!"
```

Let's look at second part of `if` expression:

`num :: Int`, but `putStrln "Invalid Number!" :: IO ()`

But they MUST have the same type!

If we rewrite `then return num`, these means type `return num :: IO Int`, but still `putStrln "Invalid Number!" :: IO ()`

First part of `if` it is not correct at all: `A` and `B` are types, not data constructors

we could write (`num > (x :: A)` ), this means same as `num > (x :: Int)`, like these:

```
num > 0 || num <= (3 :: A) || num <= (42 :: B)
```

**Updated**

Sure, name of function couldn't be `Number` with capital letter. All function are start with lowercase letter.

P.S. `n` in your example is an unused variable

Valid functions looks like:

```
numA = 3
numB = 42

number = do
    num <- fmap read getLine
    if num > 0 || num <= numA || num <= numB 
      then return (Just num)
      else putStrln "Invalid Number!" >> return Nothing
```

Comment: So basically how would i rewrite my function ?

Comment: @dcarou I add valid functions

Comment: if numA and numB change randomly , and i would not know their values, is their any way of doing it ?

Comment: Basically what i mean is: instead of having "if num >0 || num <=numA.." if i have "if num > 0 || num <= (x :: numA) || num <= (y :: numB)", is this correct ? and now the value of numA and numB may change during the program and it will still work ?

Comment: @dcarou No. But all functions are pure, so you can't write "numA=3;numA=5" - it is an error. But you could write `number numA numB = do ...` - in this case `numA` and `numB` are the parameters